# Multiple sentinel values for iter()?

Tags: python

I'm trying to get lines from a file through list comprehension until a line with '0' is reached, like so:

```
with open('input.txt', 'r') as file:
    lines = [line.strip() for line in iter(file.readline, '0')]
```

The problem is that '0' might not be on the last line, in which case it would actually be '0\n'. I know I can do

```
for line in file:
    line = line.strip()
    if line == '0':
        break
    else:
        lines.append(line)
```

But that's so hideous I can hardly stand to look at it. Am I being a drama queen? Is there a way to use both '0' and '0\n' as sentinel values, or maybe strip the readline inside iter() before the sentinel value checks it?

Comment: Something like `for line in (line.strip() for line in file):` is valid and a little less ugly IMO.

Comment: @martineau Not the answer I am looking for, but that is a great tip that I will use a lot! Thank you

Comment: The `strip()` will remove any newline at the end of the lines, so you only have to check for `'0'` — one thing — afterwards. i.e. no multiple sentinels to watch for.

Comment: To be host I find your "hideous" version to be clean, clear, readable and Pythonic.  The comprehension using `iter` is the ugly one, and the answer using `iter` + `lambda` is even worse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
with open('input.txt', 'r') as file:
    lines = [line for line in iter(lambda: str.strip(file.readline()), '0')]
```

But I somehow don't like it ...